Is the generator expression stored anywhere semantically intact?
If I set a generator
myra = (x + 100 for x in range(5))

and then later do something with it, like
for i in myra:
    print(i)

the generator has run its course, cannot be iterated over again, got that.
But is there a way, before, during, or after use, to interrogate the generator object so it returns the generating string, or something semantically equivalent?
e.g.
>>> print_the_foundation(myra)
a + 100 for a in range(5)


The generator expression isn't directly available, but myra.gi_code is the code object compiled from it. (Posted as an answer as well, but it might not be what you are looking for.)

You can get the code object produced from the generator expression.
>>> import dis
>>> myra = (x+100 for x in range(5))
>>> dis.dis(myra.gi_code)
  1           0 RETURN_GENERATOR
              2 POP_TOP
              4 RESUME                   0
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                 9 (to 30)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
             14 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (100)
             18 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             22 YIELD_VALUE              1
             24 RESUME                   1
             26 POP_TOP
             28 JUMP_BACKWARD           11 (to 8)
        >>   30 END_FOR
             32 RETURN_CONST             1 (None)
        >>   34 CALL_INTRINSIC_1         3 (INTRINSIC_STOPITERATION_ERROR)
             36 RERAISE                  1


I just segfaulted the runtime trying to buld a new function with the gi_code of a generator and trying to run it. :-)

I found a solution using the inspect module.
First, convert the generator into a lambda expression:
myra = lambda: (x + 100 for x in range(5))

Next, define the print_the_foundation to extract the generator part:
def print_the_foundation(gen_function):
    source_lines, _ = inspect.getsourcelines(gen_function)
    source_code = ''.join(source_lines).strip()

    start = source_code.find('(')
    generator_expression = source_code[start + 1:-1]

    return generator_expression

print_the_foundation(myra)

Output:
x + 100 for x in range(5)

To access the generator you first need to call the myra.
If you want to iterate over the generator you can do it like this:
for i in myra():
    print(i)

Or you can create a generator by calling the function and storing it in a separate variable:
myra_gen = myra()

print(next(myra_gen))  # 100
print(next(myra_gen))  # 101


so, i tried this, but next(myra) does not return a result now, instead 'TypeError: 'function'object is not an iterator'

@bukwyrm myra is a function that returns a generator now. You need to call it to get the generator.

ok, i'm clearly out of my depth here: next(myra()) returns 100, but the following next(myra()) also returns 100 (instead of 101) - how do i make myra behave like an iterator again?

i see, so instead of reading the 'source' of the generator, we define a lambda (that includes the generator), and then read the source of THAT. This A is only adjacent to my Q, but not quite it, honestly. I learned something anyways, so thank you for that. As an aside: inspect.getsourcelines does not work from the console, just in a script.

How do you call print_the_foundation?

@nocomment print_the_foundation(myra)

Ok. In that case I was going to say the parameter name is misleading, but you already improved that :-). (Still maybe a little misleading, as "generator function" is an established term understood as something else, but I guess it's good enough).
